# XSLT mapping element names

Tags: xslt, dictionary, element

I want to write a XSLT stylesheet that maps element names by some mapping rules. To make the stylesheet customizable for a less experienced user I want to store the map seperatly like this inside the stylesheet:

```
<mr:mapping-rules>
    <field src="field1" dest="field1337" />
    <field src="field2" dest="field2" />
    <field src="field3" dest="field3" />
</mr:mapping-rules>
```

Here is some example input data:

```
<Record>
    <field1>123</field1>
    <field2>asd</field2>
    <field3>456</field3>
</Record>
```

The expected result is:

```
<Record>
    <field1337>123</field1337>
    <field2>asd</field2>
    <field3>456</field3>
</Record>
```

It would be nice if anyone could give me a hint how the template must look like.

Comment: First of all I would suggest not to list fields that are not supposed to be changed. Then I wonder whether the mapping does not need to include a context like a parent or ancestor path. And I would then suggest to solve the problem by writing one stylesheet that takes the mapping file and produces a new stylesheet that implements the particular mapping for a given mapping file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, based on the comment I made. I wrote one stylesheet taking a mapping file in the form

```
<mr:mapping-rules xmlns:mr="http://example.com/mr">
  <context pattern="Record">
    <field src="field1" dest="field1337" />
  </context>
</mr:mapping-rules>
```

to generate a stylesheet in the form

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record/field1">
      <xsl:element name="field1337">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet that creates the above stylesheet as its output is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mr="http://example.com/mr"
  xmlns:oxsl="http://example.com/xsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="oxsl mr">

<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="oxsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <oxsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <oxsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <oxsl:copy>
        <oxsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </oxsl:copy>
    </oxsl:template>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </oxsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mr:mapping-rules/context/field">
  <oxsl:template match="{../@pattern}/{@src}">
    <oxsl:element name="{@dest}">
      <oxsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </oxsl:element>
  </oxsl:template>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you can run the generated stylesheet on an input like

```
<Root>
  <Record-List>
    <Record>
      <field1>foo</field1>
      <field2>bar</field2>
      <field3>baz</field3>
    </Record>
  </Record-List>
</Root>
```

and it outputs

```
<Root>
  <Record-List>
    <Record>
      <field1337>foo</field1337>
      <field2>bar</field2>
      <field3>baz</field3>
    </Record>
  </Record-List>
</Root>
```

Of course the mapping file could be adapted to your needs, I mainly tried to show a sample generating a second stylesheet from the mapping file to be then applied to an input sample.

Comment: Good solution. There are many cases like this where it's appropriate to think of the input data as defining a set of transformation rules, which can be translated to XSLT transformation rules by using XSLT itself.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's solution is a good one, in that the approach is very powerful and extensible, but it's also possible to solve the problem more directly:

```
<xsl:key name="mappings" match="mr:mapping-rules/field" use="@src"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{(key('mappings', name())/@dest, name())[1]}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a shorter way to solve the problem. But I think I'll use the more flexible solution above. Nonetheless thanks for the reply!